# How can I use API call in *ngFor

Tags: angular, api

I want to use temperature by city in my table as follows. I have other data hardcoded ,however, temperature data needs to be fetched from API. I am getting the data successfully from API with given city name, but trying to figure out how I can render it in table.

Component file

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Event[];
  selectedEvent: any;
  temperature:any;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService,
              private weatherService: WeatherService) { }


  loadTemperature(city: string){
    this.weatherService.getWeather(city).subscribe(data =>{
      this.temperature = data.current.temp_c;
    })
```

Template file

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Event Id</td>
      <td>Event Name</td>
      <td>Session Time</td>
      <td>City</td>
      <td>Temperature</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let event of events">
    <tr (click)="onSelect(event)">
      <td>{{event.id}}</td>
      <td>{{event.name}}</td>
      <td>{{event.time}}</td>
      <td>{{event.city}}</td>
      <td>{{**HERE I NEED TEMP BY CITY**}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Please suggest me the ways I can tackle this problem. 
I used following tricks but not successful

```
<td *ngIf = "loadTemperature(event.city)">{{temperature}}</td>
<td>{{loadTemperature(event.city)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want multiple `tbody` tags, so you should put the `*ngFor` on the `<tr>`, besides that you can use the `async` pipe to get what you want:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let event of events" (click)="onSelect(event)">
    <td>{{event.id}}</td>
    <td>{{event.name}}</td>
    <td>{{event.time}}</td>
    <td>{{event.city}}</td>
    <td>{{ loadTemperature(event.city) | async }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Where you have to change your `loadTemperature` function to return an `Observable`:

```
loadTemperature(city: string): Observable<number> {
  this.weatherService.getWeather(city).pipe(
    map((data) => data.current.temp_c),
    shareReplay(1)
  });
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what this will do for your performance, it might even keep calling the same api over and over, because of the `*ngFor`. Perhaps adding a `trackBy` will resolve this.

Better though, would be to add the temperature inside the `events`. But to show you, I need to know how you obtain this `events` array.

Considering you have it hard-coded somewhere, you can do something like this:

```
events: Event[] = this.eventService.events;
events$ = of(this.events).pipe(
  concatMap((events) => forkJoin(
    ...events.map((event) => this.loadTemperature(event.city).pipe(
      tap((temp) => event.temp = temp)
    )
  )
);
```

And you need to update your template to use the new observable:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let event of events$ | async" (click)="onSelect(event)">
    <td>{{event.id}}</td>
    <td>{{event.name}}</td>
    <td>{{event.time}}</td>
    <td>{{event.city}}</td>
    <td>{{event.temp}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There is a typo with the semicolon location

Comment: @YoukouleleY it's gone! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a "bad idea" call a function in a *ngFor (Angular "repaint" a *ngFor several times). You must use forkJoin to make all the calls together and change the array. It's more or less like bellow (note: I don't check the code, take it as an idea)

```
AddTemperatures(events:any[])
{
    //create an array of "calls" -an array of Observables-
     conts obs:Observable[]=events.map(even=>{
         return this.weatherService.getWeather(even.city);
     })
     //forkJoin realize all the calls together and
     //put the result in an array, so 
     //result[0] becomes the temperature of events[0].city
     //result[1] becomes the temperature of events[1].city ...
     return forkJoin(obs).pipe(map(result=>{
        //with result, for each event add the property "temperature"
        events.ForEach((event:any,index)=>{
           event.temperature=result[index]
        })
        }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to the question.
I created two separate components in the main component. Here is the structure.

Home Component
 -- EventListComponent
   -- EventComponent

Now I iterated ngFor loop in list component as follows.
EventListComponent

```
export class EventListComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Event[];

  constructor(private eventService: EventService,
             ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.eventsChanged.subscribe((events: Event[]) => {
      this.events = events;
    });
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
  }
```

EventListComponentTemplate

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <b>Event ID</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <b>Event Name</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <b>Session Time</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <b>City</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <b>Temperature</b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <app-event
        *ngFor="let e of events; let i = index"
        [event]="e"
        [index]="i">
      </app-event>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used data binding and gave a single event to the event Component. 
Event Compoenent

```
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() event: Event;
  temp: string;
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTemperature(this.event.city);
  }

  loadTemperature(city: string) {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherByCity(city).subscribe(data =>{
      this.temp = data.current.temp_c;
    })
  }
}
```

EventComponent template

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center" style="cursor: pointer; margin: 15px 0;"
       [routerLink]="index"
       routerLinkActive="active">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      {{index}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      {{event.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      {{event.time}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      {{event.city}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      {{temp}}C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As in the event component, I have a single event, I can easily assign the temperature to the city by API call.

Thanks, everyone for the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way -

```
loadTemperature(city: string){
    return this.weatherService.getWeather(city).pipe(map(x => x.current.temp_c));
<td>{{loadTemperature(event.city) | async}}</td>
```

Comment: Downvoters can you help me with comment as your view instead of just downvoting this?

Comment: so you should post a comment instead of just downvoting the answer, Anyways check in function whether data is coming from API or not

Comment: @PardeepJain don't think he downvoted though, but you are returning a subscription, and using `async` on that. Async only works on observables

Comment: Ah, Yeah that could be my mistake in answer, thanks @PierreDuc for pointing out. Anyways your answer seems to be work out.

Comment: Please replace `subscribe` with `pipe` and `map`